Why am I getting hum on Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu
I'm running a Raspberry Pi 4 using Ubuntu. When I try to connect it to a Digital Audio Converter, I'm encountering a very unpleasant hum. I assume this is related to the fact that Raspberry Pi is ungrounded. Any ideas on how fix this?
Release details: 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-1004-raspi aarch64)

Is this Ubuntu specific issue? Is the issue present in Raspberry Pi forum? In case it is some issue with the electronic circuit, you will have better luck finding a solution in the Raspberry Pi forum.

"Hum" (at 60Hz) is almost always a grounding problem.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I don't know if this is an Ubuntu problem or a Raspberry Pi problem. I'm starting here.
